# Perl: Is it possible to install Mysql module without having Mysql installation?

Tags: mysql, perl

I'm trying to install the Mysql module on my development machine but it seems to want a local Mysql installation before it will install.

Is there a work around?

I don't need or want a local installation of Mysql, I'm querying a network machine with the installation.

Answer (score 8):

`DBD::mysql` is a wrapper around the MySQL client libraries. You will at least need to install a client, just like you would need to a client to connect to a remove MySQL server anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what system you're on or how you are trying to install DBD::mysql.
You'll need the client libraries (and if you're installing from CPAN - the source of the client libraries) but you should not need MySQL Server. If on a linux the mysql-server package is a dependency of DBD::mysql, it would be a bug.